# Delete on batch

Tags: oracle, oracle9i, delete-row

I have a database table that has >14 million rows.

If I attempt to perform:

```
 delete from table
```

The connection hangs out.

How can I delete all the rows, in "batches" so they are deleted eventually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out:

```
truncate table tblname
```

This has the advantage of not being rollback-able so will not have to log its actions, and also does not fire triggers. That makes it substantially faster than the equivalent `delete from tblname`.

Otherwise, you can work out subsets to delete, based on your table data. For example, if there's a field (hopefully indexed) containing last names:

```
delete from tblname where lastname like 'A%'
```

Note that this is just an example. You can also use things like

- salary (<20K, 20K-40K, 40K-60K, ...).
- SSN.
- current balance.

and so on. What you choose depends entirely on the table you're trying to delete.

I prefer the `truncate` command myself due to its simplicity.

Comment: Nope.. what it does?  Does it delete everything without a transaction or something?

Comment: Well ehem I already knew it, you know, I just wanted to do a "jeopardy type of question"  from the FAQ *It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question.*  je je je Thank paxdiablo

Comment: Huh? Are you talking to yourself?

Comment: @Oscar, you are indeed right that these sorts of questions are okay. @ceejayoz, that sort of discourse normally comes about when one party to a conversation deletes their comments, making what's left seem disjointed. It may be that someone had a comment in between Oscar's two along the lines of "Oscar, you seem knowledgeable about SQL in all your other questions - surely you knew this" and then deleted it. That would make the current state understandable.

Answer (score 2):

**deletes** are logged operation which can be rolled back, hence they can be quite slow.  If you can **truncate** or drop and recreate the table, that's your best bet.  Alternatively, you can [execute this sql](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/PL_SQL/PLSQL_3.shtml).

```
BEGIN
loop 
  delete from table where rownum < 500
  exit when SQL%rowcount < 499
end loop;
END
```